# iAd reducing FPS?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad, frame-rate

Does iAd banner reduces FPS?

Indeed, since I added iAd my FSP is shit. I was 59 all game and now it's variable from 35-50 FPS.

Any ideas please because my game is almost not playable with this banner.

Thank for help.

Comment: device ? simulator fps are meaningless.

Comment: Many recent questions suggesting that iAd started to slow down games (Sprite Kit as well). Perhaps an issue specific to the iOS 8 beta?

Comment: Thanx for answers.

I develop with iOS 7.1 version not version beta 8.

I launch all on my device directly not with simulator.

Thx.

Comment: I recently added iAd in a 7.1 game, and noted no perceivable user experience degradation (nor measured) ... but - i force clamp the fps at 30 since i feel that jitter is the most critical factor when appreciating game play smoothness. If you can afford to do it, try that. Riding shotgun on as close to 60 fps as possible produces an almost certain jitterbug game on iSomethings.

Comment: Hello YvesBlorg, sorry but I did not get your advice can you reformulate please :-) (I am french lol).

Comment: Je force volontairement le FPS a 30, mes jeux sont conçus ainsi. Ça a tendance a éliminer les fluctuations (qui sont plus irritantes pour le gamer que la lenteur). Ainsi, j'ai 33 ms par cycle de rafraichissement pour faire tout ce qui doit être fait, et j'ai toujours beaucoup de réserve dans le cycle. Donc, iAd n'affecte pas l'expérience utilisateur du gamer. Par contre, si tu fais des 'pans' rapides sur la scène de jeu, 30 fps peut devenir irritant. À tester.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, mais ça ne change pas grand chose, du coup le tout est un peu moins fluide. Je vais tout de même rester sur du 30FPS, merci encore !

Comment: @Niknolty : Urghhh ... bon, je vais retester mon bidule en scène de combat :)

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies on this. First to begin with how much time does a frame in your game take. That is different from if it runs at 60 fps. 60 fps works out to 18.6 ms. How much time of that does your game take per frame? Do we know the max frame time iAD can take? I don't think the ads can be pushed off to another thread as the bottleneck seems to be their rendering. Even if you could push it to another thread, you will only benefit on multiple core processors.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the iAd logic in your `UINavigationController` subclass that was set in the `appDelegate`. At mine code it look like:

```
AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    // Enable multiple touches
    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

//FEW LINES LATER

    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [self checkDeviceType];

    // setup iAds bannerView
    [self setupIADs];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:navController_];

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)setupIADs {
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    float bannerHeight = _isiPadRunning ? 66.0f : 50.0f;
    ADAdType bannerType = _isiPadRunning ? ADAdTypeMediumRectangle : ADAdTypeBanner;
    _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:bannerType];
    _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, navController_.view.frame.size.height, size.width, bannerHeight);

    CGSize newBannerSize = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(size.width, bannerHeight)];
    _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, navController_.view.frame.size.height,
                                   newBannerSize.width, newBannerSize.height);
    _bannerView.delegate = self;

    //get view
    UIView *mainView = [navController_ view];
    [mainView addSubview:_bannerView];
    [mainView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

As you can see I use `navController_` to place an iAd banner view. No FPS drops! :)
Please, try it out. For me it helped and I have no FPS drops or delay. Everything works great.