# iAd banner reduces fps

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad, frame-rate, banner, spritebuilder

Does iAd banner reduces FPS?
I have cocos2d project created by Spritebuilder.
Indeed, since I added iAd my FPS is terrible. I was 60 all game and now it's variable from 35-50 FPS.
Any ideas please because my game is almost not playable with this banner.

Thank for help

Comment: Search around. This has been asked many times before. Yes, iAd for whatever reasons started to drag down fps since sometime recently (ie iOS 7.1 or 8.0 beta).

Answer (score 0):

try to reduce the fill rate of the iad

also see here: [iAd reducing FPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450192/iad-reducing-fps?rq=1)